# Multiple Received: from in Original Message in Gmail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails using PHPMailer. Its working fine but in Gmail when I have checked, Its showing me Multiple Received From information which is exposing my server information instead of SMTP server.

```
Delivered-To: mygmail@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:6a20:289f:b0:134:8df0:38f2 with SMTP id q31csp2499936pzf;
        Thu, 20 Jul 2023 21:07:59 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APBJJlGUdtfqZSKhrqY5gy30KUrovK+JgSQfyS1KcTm3lLSvehmvEI+MrNARPjPFzDuDpfyfmebP
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6870:3282:b0:1b0:2d25:f5ae with SMTP id q2-20020a056870328200b001b02d25f5aemr898724oac.47.1689912479685;
        Thu, 20 Jul 2023 21:07:59 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1689912479; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=raNw8UyJ273/lmRHrYlSSOP/4tjrWEZgOK2NGlqkYhQfGkhv/LQfDQJr0fbsOD6Q4u
         IQUMZhJLVmCSXI6NkhLnJtNTs6l/w4NsIA3gRqdbMm725WRugwItWThCO/hVZBELVmHT
         bL67mPDppKSGOn6ynGrx7HCjwDpyPyubg2dCv65Z8u/jjXqXGmz26FFK4Q3NEWWKMLmQ
         64J/LotDOWkWzZ7LVpSpmg9KsnY1LZqtMeutfZZAoO4DU8akfW9OwQtGb9LdexzlJks2
         Gel4UIfrPkaFGAJx4cEtlaY54KYTkk1Ui6adsMCjcUp1hDgz3ZstjSp6cDPsLaUv+zTO
         bCDw==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=mime-version:message-id:subject:from:to:date:dkim-signature;
        bh=bIDjwW/gXuMp99hIYSKpyBdpvCx8uFr77qlql7C/iAo=;
        fh=38P0F8Oks2zx3dfUfXd63HKtV+2/22/mUQuXfmmtf+4=;
        b=H3jfjyV018ufJ1PpmlRMLMuVVRHWMwbzy8goD3Xbo2rhaZQ8yzAo5S9vXL3cgO639Z
         C2/q5GoWIerlzGNWVUySbwuBhYJ9ZuZiaEG14aDZvc9V03JthfwS3sYaBXoFIdgCLZDV
         KH8V1iWQMMmX232X/pJZSMKPHo4qeYmkNkLNNXGnCBA1Ncc75+fY37djD+pL64PPrtN+
         Sv51ES40zJTtiLH3w/M5xcyrTKm/Rhur2W220bNFXaMs6l/mzp64gnXL/v+y47OZX9Gw
         hp7zM7AyBa2/HFVmE/LpzqvGzFxx36HpeXV3kheFBJxp/WOunLyUHC5lRXcwTqRswl6o
         kzIw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@examplesmtp.com header.s=mail header.b=dHe3YPZJ;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of darnell@examplesmtp.com designates 02.02.02.02 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=darnell@examplesmtp.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=examplesmtp.com
Return-Path: <darnell@examplesmtp.com>
Received: from server.examplesmtp.com (server.examplesmtp.com. [02.02.02.02])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id z10-20020a05687041ca00b001baa7691f53si1163446oac.314.2023.07.20.21.07.59
        for <mygmail@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Thu, 20 Jul 2023 21:07:59 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of darnell@examplesmtp.com designates 02.02.02.02 as permitted sender) client-ip=02.02.02.02;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@examplesmtp.com header.s=mail header.b=dHe3YPZJ;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of darnell@examplesmtp.com designates 02.02.02.02 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=darnell@examplesmtp.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=examplesmtp.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=examplesmtp.com; s=mail; h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject: From:To:Date:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID: Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe: List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=bIDjwW/gXuMp99hIYSKpyBdpvCx8uFr77qlql7C/iAo=; b=dHe3YPZJi1MdY5hFwOwcwbaPtv TH17w7bJm2uqc188DLBrZX6e59UIXGCOX4F2rc7idgInsH1LjaZ3fmntx3dmQfTZySobf5CyLjim6 xYtUkdq2U9SZy7HBW8U+IGbC3ethu+koRnxb2rspyQ6/2vkqv6AB8Q+A/OpL1KpHEEGk=;
Received: from my.server.com ([01.01.01.01] helo=server.examplesmtp.com) by server.examplesmtp.com with esmtpsa
  (TLS1.3) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (Exim 4.94.2) (envelope-from <darnell@examplesmtp.com>) id 1qMhQt-005Xhj-Bj for mygmail@gmail.com; Fri, 21 Jul 2023 04:07:59 +0000
Date: Fri, 21 Jul 2023 04:07:58 +0000
To: mygmail@gmail.com
From: Darnell Collins <darnell@examplesmtp.com>
Subject: Update on Your Ticket: ID {{ random_number }}
Message-ID: <QiIFKmlxcLpJXTocKXTuPXif2UxTtLsMhwTCk4ELURQ@server.examplesmtp.com>
X-Originating-IP: server.examplesmtp.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

I hope this email finds you well. I wanted to inform you that we have made some recent updates to your ticket, ID {{ random_number }}, and would greatly appreciate it if you could take a moment to review and acknowledge the changes.

If you have any questions or require further assistance, please don't hesitate to reply to this email. We are here to help.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Best Regards,
```

and my code is like this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host       = $s_server;
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Username   = $s_username;
        $mail->Password   = $s_password;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = $s_protocol;
        $mail->Port       = $s_port;
        $mail->Hostname = $s_server;
        $mail->XMailer = ' ';
        $mail->addCustomHeader('X-Originating-IP: '.$s_server);
        
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
       'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        ); 
    
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($s_from, $s_from_name);
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $template;

        $mail->send();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        
    }
```

[image]

I think its signing multiple time. I have posted question on [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2933) but no luck. I do not know how to prevent it. Let e know if anyone here can help me for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with PHPMailer. `server.examplesmtp.com` did not generate the mail out of thin air itself - it received it _from_ `my.server.com`. If you don't like that this info gets added to the mail - then you would have to find yourself an SMTP server that does _not_ add this info to the mail headers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using PHPMailer to send emails using Gmail SMTP server.

One solution is to add a `Reply-To` field in your email headers.
Another solution is to use `BCC` (blind carbon copy) instead of `To` when adding multiple recipients to your email.

Oleksandr in freelancer site.

Comment: You answer isn't about topic starter question